# MSProject VSTO Lambda Get with custom field is very slow

Tags: c#, plugins, lambda, interop, ms-project

I'm developing an vsto plugin for microsoft project, and all went well until one day.
The problem is what my schedule is very big, maybe 39k tasks (lines) or more... i use lambda expression to get my tasks and work like this simple follow code: 
`var lstTasks = Project.Tasks.Cast<MSProject.Task>().Where(w => !w.Summary).ToList();`

`var lstTasksInesperado = lstTasks.Where(w => w.GetField(App.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Tipo Manutenção")).ToLower().Equals("i")).ToList();`

first, i get all my tasks where is not summary and convert to a list.
second, i get my tasks where my **CUSTOM FIELD (Pwa CustomField)** called Tipo Manutencao is equals "**i**" and is now what my problem started.
This second query is very, very slow... like 3 maybe 4 hours.
This problem started whitout any explication... but is very persistent.

Obs: I have this problem only in some schedules (mpp), normally when it is in pwa.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need 2 lists  or only one ? Do you need to load all 39k records if yes why ?

Comment: Yes, i need 2 lists, because for each list, i need separate filters
but, it's not the point.
yes, i need load 39k or more records because i development an report, and this 39k of records is only my tasks when is not summary.
this schedule is very big.

Comment: You mention that this is a problem only in some schedules, what is the run time like in schedules that aren't affected, and how many tasks do they have?

Comment: hi @JonIles
many schedules have same tasks count, but execution time is very fast, like 30, 40 seconds.

Comment: For the affected schedules, do they always have the long run time, or do you sometimes get good performance?

Comment: @JonIles They already had their execution time much smaller, the problem is that now it was much slower. I was able to work around the problem by removing the baselines and creating them again.

Comment: @JonIles sorry for the time, i solved my problem using IQueryable for each selects. thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved using the `IQueryable` interface for selects.